# Android real time messaging

Tags: android, client-server, real-time-data

i m trying to develop an aap. in android which behaves like a client/server architecture.
my app communicates messages to server to rout to specified clients..

i have heard that this could be accomplished by a REAL TIME MESSAGING client.

i have to pass only text based data. no audio/video streaming

Answer (score 2):

You can read up on XMPP:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol
http://xmpp.org/

There are client apis available for Android, I have personally used asmack:
http://code.google.com/p/asmack/